# Getting date and time using HtmlAgilityPack from my website for unity

Tags: c#, parsing, xpath, unity-game-engine, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to grab the date and time from my website http://www.thisisnotaballgame.com/time using the code here. The issue is I'm getting the line before it becomes a date and time and it's an iframe. Is there any way I can translate the html I grab from my site into the date and time or am I going about this in the wrong way? I'm using unity3d as well.

```
public string url = "http://www.thisisnotaballgame.com/time";


IEnumerator Start ()
{
    url = "http://www.thisisnotaballgame.com/time";
    WWW www = new WWW ( url );
    yield return www;
    //renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
    ExtractTimeFromBytes ( www.bytes );
}

void ExtractTimeFromBytes ( byte[] websiteBytes )
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream ( websiteBytes );

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument ();
    doc.Load ( stream );
    foreach ( HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//iframe") )
    {
        string linkTxt = link.OuterHtml;
    }
    doc.Save ( "file.txt" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to get the date for that `DateTime.UtcNow` doesn't provide?

Anyways, the URL of the iframe is http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i3dcvasg/n1440/tt0/tw0/tm2/th1/tb1 and that's the url you should be grabbing the source from.

Comment: Good job, thats what I was about to say :)

Comment: I can't trust the local device time as people can change it to manipulate my reward system. So it looks like the line I should be grabbing is <span id=t1>11/14/2012, 00:10:21</span>?

Comment: @WillieWight Yes, that would give you the date and time up to the second.

Comment: and you can't trust what you pull from the internet because someone could just redirect free.timeanddate.com in their hosts file to localhost. etc. etc. I think an easier way to prevent users using clock manipulation is start a Stopwatch when the event actually happens, then you can just tell the server "the user did X 15 seconds ago" and let the server figure out what time it was.